# Is there another issue that can cause css files not been found on django project?

Tags: python, css, django

I am sorry to ask  very repeated question. However, I have tried my best for many days yet cannot figure it out. Could anyone guide me what I have done wrong?

I tried to create a library program by django. This is my files' directory:

```
prophado_lib
|_prophado_lib
   |_  __pycache__
   |_  __init__.py
   |_  settings.py
   |_  urls.py
   |_  wsgi.py
|_book_management
   |_  __pycache__
   |_ migrations
   |_ static
      |_ css
         |_ style.css
   |_ Templates
      |_ index.html
   |_  __init__.py
   |_ admin.py
   |_ apps.py
   |_ models.py
   |_ tests.py
   |_ views.py 
|_dbsqlite3
|_manage.py
```

Then my code in each file are as follows:

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>

<h1>{{var1}}</h1>
Welcome to Propado School Library!
```

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from book_management import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^my_index/', views.index),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

fyi, I have already tried other ways with *STATIC_ROOT* and *python manage.py collectstatic* , even though I have known that it's for when I would like to make it in to production.

Comment: How are you running django?

Comment: You didn't include your app name `book_management` to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I used "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" and open localhost:8000/my_index

Comment: @mhhabib I haven't seen anybody include the app's name in ```INSTALL_APPS``` also. How should I do?

Comment: @Jiberellin your static file is in the `book_management` apps. So don't you should add your app's name in the project settings?

Comment: @mhhabib Millions Thanks. I have managed to do it. Just put the ```'book_management'``` in ```INSTALLED_APPS```.  I am really really a newbie. XD Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your configuration looks ok just needs to install your `book_management` app

in settings.py add your app under the INSTALLED_APP list
`INSTALLED_APPS=['book_management.apps.BookManagementConfig']`